# Пустой результат после CURL

Tags: php, curl

Задача: осуществлять поиск слова "Пупок" на сайте "Абв". 
Сайт "Абв" представляет собой большую таблицу, по которой мне нужно проверить наличие слова "Пупок". 
Думаю для начала получить содержимое сайта "Абв" (которое ежедневно меняется), затем записать всё это в файл и осуществлять поиск слова по файлу.
Итак, хочу получить содержимое сайта, пишу:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$link = "http://Абв/";
$html = file_get_contents_curl($link);
echo "<a>".$html."</a>";
```

Но результат - пустая страница. Что интересно - с другим сайтом всё работает. В чём загвоздка?  ПРошу помощи.
ИЛи же есть более простой способ поиска слова на другом сайте?
Спасибо!

Comment: вы вот возьмите и проверьте на обычном `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Выдает ошибку "failed to open stream". Решением было заменить на file_get_contents_curl().